# How to remove duplicate span tag in xml twig?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I need to merge `span` tags with the same style in the following XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<book>
<p><span style="font-size:10pt;">T</span><span style="font-size:10pt;">h</span><span style="font-size:10pt;">e</span></p>
<p><span style="font-style:italic;">o</span><span style="font-style:italic;">f</span><span style="font-size:10pt;">e</span></p>
</book>
```

My desired output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<book>
<p><span style="font-size:10pt;">The</span></p>
<p><span style="font-style:italic;">of</span><span style="font-size:10pt;">e</span></p>
</book>
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
use strict;
use XML::Twig;
my $Document = XML::Twig->new(
        keep_encoding=>1,                                              
        twig_handlers =>{
        },
pretty_print => 'indented',
);
$Document->parsefile("book.xml");
$Document->print();
```

I am having difficulty understanding the concepts of this module. Is what I am trying to do possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're not really removing XML tags there - as far as XML is concerned, each `span` is an independent entity.

However, what you can do is use the `XML::Twig::Elt` method `prev_sibling` - because that looks at nodes at the same level. And if the previous node is of the right type, and same style - concat the current text, and delete this node. I'm not sure this'll work for all use cases, but it'll do what you ask.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $previous_span;
my $previous_style;

sub merge_span {
    my ( $twig, $span ) = @_;
    my $prev = $span->prev_sibling;
    if (    $prev
        and $prev->tag eq $span->tag
        and $prev->att('style') eq $span->att('style')
        and not $prev -> has_children
        and not $span -> has_children
        )
    {
        $prev->set_text( $prev->text . $span->text );
        $span->delete;
    }
}

my $xml = XML::Twig->new(
    'pretty_print'  => 'indented',
    'twig_handlers' => { 'span' => \&merge_span, },
);
$xml->parse( \*DATA );
$xml->print;


__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<book>
<p><span style="font-size:10pt;">T</span><span style="font-size:10pt;">h</span><span style="font-size:10pt;">e</span></p>
<p><span style="font-style:italic;">o</span><span style="font-style:italic;">f</span><span style="font-size:10pt;">e</span></p>
</book>
```